# Numpy dot product on specific dimension

Tags: python, numpy, dot-product

I have a numpy array `a` of shape `(x, y)` and another array `b` of shape `(x, z)`

I'm trying to get the dot product between each row (dimension `x`) of `a` and `b`. Desired result: `x` amount of matrixes of shape `(x, y)` or a matrix of shape `(x, y, z)`.

Comment: Are you sure you want a `dot`?  Which axis are you summing?  The result dimension looks more like an outer product.  `a[:,:,None] * b[:,None,:]`

Comment: `matmul` can also handle this by adding a size 1 dimension for the `sum-of-products`, `a[:,:,None]@b[:,None,:]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use einsum -

```
import numpy as np

a = np.random.rand(10, 20)
b = np.random.rand(10, 30)

c = np.einsum('ij,ik->ijk', a, b)

print(c.shape)
```